Parcel tracking on a world map
I'm getting a package shipped from the USA to Germany and would like to see where the parcel is currently located, and which stations it took - on a map.
Are there any tools that offer this feature for USPS (United States Postal Service) tracking IDs?
It should support fetching the data from the USPS API and have locations for the the facilities like "USPS Facility, HIGHLAND, CA 92346" and "USPS Regional Facility, LAS VEGAS NV DISTRIBUTION CENTER"
